# Sliding Swivel Rotating hung panel door

Tags: wood, doors, prehung

Good day,

I would like to hang a wooden door panel and for it to be able to slide and rotate. Can anyone suggest the hardware necessary for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You really are going to have to be more specific about your interest, lest we think you want something like the Klemens Torggler door: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umfvm8I9_oU

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  Neat, can see me wanting one(till I see price tag).